# Java Deserialization PickleType Column

Tags: deserialization, pickle

I am currently working on a project to make a program in Python Flask with Java Spring.
But some data is storing python dictionary as Postgresql PickleType column.
So, the data type that I look up in the DB is as follows.

'''
0x800495D8000000000000007D94288C057175657279945D947D94288C0B70726F647563745F747970944B018C0B70726F647563745F636E74944B328C05636F756E74944B018C0970726963655F74686294473FF00000000000008C057072696365944D611E...
'''

How can I deserialize this to an object in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Three simple but not so simple options comes in mind first:

1. Normalize the data with a Python script. Write a Python script to unpickle the column data and export to other created Postgresql columns, which can then be mapped in Java as usual;
2. Use Python in between to turn your Pickle data into meaningful data in Java. [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) could help in [this task](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InputOutput/#pickle) as [it has Java integration](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JythonAndJavaIntegration/#using-jython-within-java-applications) (compatibility to be verified). People have discussed about unpickling Python data with Jython before. [Read more on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616060/how-to-unpickle-a-file-in-java).
3. Use Python from Postgre. PostgreSQL allows using custom languages as Procedural Language, and [Python is one of them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpython.html).

---

It's advisable to get a grasp of what type of data is stored in this column, as it represent Python objects there may be complex objects stored which may rule out some of your options.

---

Pickle is strongly coupled with Python. AFAIK, There's no easy way to simply convert Pickle from Java without going through Python. From [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json):

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for **serializing and
> de-serializing a Python object structure**. “Pickling” is the process
> whereby a **Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and
> “unpickling” is the inverse operation**, whereby a byte stream (from a
> binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object
> hierarchy. Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as
> “serialization”, “marshalling,” or “flattening”; however, to avoid
> confusion, the terms used here are “pickling” and “unpickling”.